# DesignInstance does not show the sample data assigned to

Tags: c#, wpf

I am using Visual Studio 2017 15.8.5 and I am not able to make the DesignInstance work.
I started a blank project to test it and It's showing me the name of the property instead of the sample data that I assigned it.

[image]

Here is my user control :

```
public partial class SampleUserControl : UserControl
{
    public SampleUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

The XAML code of the user control:

```
<UserControl x:Class="***.GUI.SampleUserControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:***.GUI"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="100" d:DesignWidth="300" Background="White"
             d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance local:SampleViewModelWithData,
                                                CreateList=False,
                                                IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}">
    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <local:SampleViewModel />
    </UserControl.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}" 
                   TextAlignment="Center" 
                   VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                   FontSize="32" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

The View Model :

```
class SampleViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private string m_Value = string.Empty;
    public string Value
    {
        get => m_Value;
        set
        {
            m_Value = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Value"));
        }
    }

    public SampleViewModel() { }
}
```

And the derived class of the view model with some data :

```
class SampleViewModelWithData : SampleViewModel
{
    public SampleViewModelWithData() : base()
    {
        Value = "ABC";
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Is there any special requirement that you want to see the data on design time and can not run the project?

Comment: Not especially. It's more to know why it does not work when it seems to work just fine on other computers.